# Spring Boot - Keycloak valid redirect Returning 404

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

Good day coders.
I am fairly new to docker and keycloak.
I have a keycloak container and a spring boot application.
I am using oauth2
Below is my config
application-docker.yml fule

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          MyRealm:
            client-id: myclient
            redirect-url: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/myclient"
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - email
              - roles
        provider:
          MyRealm:
            issuer-uri: "http://localhost:8080/realms/myRealm"
```

and my docker compose file

```
 keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.4
    command: ["start-dev","--import-realm"]
.
.
.
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    expose:
      - "8090"
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
    depends_on:
      keycloak-postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - astro_network
```

When I call my spring boot application from the browser, i get

```
http://keycloak:8080/realms/myRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?
```

404 error.
but when it returns

````
http://keycloak:8090/realms/myRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?
```, 
the app works. But when I change the issuer-uri "http://localhost:8090/realms/myRealm", the app doesn't even run in the docker environment.
In my keycloak container, I set the valid redirect uris to "http://localhost:7013/*"
How do I fix this issue

I change the issuer-uri "http://localhost:8090/realms/myRealm", the app doesn't even run in the docker environment
````